# How to plot a million points on a map with folium in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, leaflet, jupyter-notebook, gis, folium

I would like to have a zoomable/dragable map on which I can plot a million points (GPS traces) in Jupyter Notebook (Python).

I understand that it is not necessary to plot a million point at the same time, but I would like the map to look like [this](https://scontent.fbru2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/11103190_519617272932_665863130878066487_o.jpg?_nc_cat=103&_nc_ht=scontent.fbru2-1.fna&oh=e418f15fb78d50b9397d41111507452b&oe=5C888EDD) and have all points in the visible area be shown at the same time, or a visually indistinguishable subset.

Folium will not let me show more than 3000 points on any map in Jupyter Notebook (by comparison, Tableau does 1 million quite easily).

What solutions exist to do this kind of interactive maps? If it is necessary to pre-compute map tiles, how is this done?

Comment: i don't think this is possible with folium (or rather, the underlying leaflet.js). i host a map with roughly 500 markers, each of which is rendered as separate object, and you can already feel it slugging down the browser.  one million and more would be simply unusable.

Comment: I agree with @MCO, a million would be tough.  Maybe have a look at folium's FastMarkerClusters().  I've used it to plot 30k points.  Not sure it would scale to a million though

Comment: Oh, and maybe [datashader](https://github.com/pyviz/datashader)